# Django all_auth and custom form

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-registration

I'm using django allauth for social login/signup. Also, I've my own signup form as an alternate login/signup. Following are the fields that I'm fetching from the user in the alternate form.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    col2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

So, when the user signs up, it asks for additional fields as well(`col1`, `col2`), apart from `username`, `email` and `password`.

Following is the signup view.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, user_email, user_pass)
Profile.objects.create(user=user, col1=col1, col2=col2)
return
```

So, whenever the user signs up via the alternate form, the above view is called up.

Now, in contrast, when the user signs up from social account FB, it does not ask for extra info, ie `col1/col2`. It directly signs up without asking for extra info, neither I want it to ask.

I then create a row in `Profile` model post signup using signals.

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def create_profile(request, user, sociallogin=None, **kwargs):
    if sociallogin:
        if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':
            data = sociallogin.account.extra_data
            col1 = data.get('col1')
            col2 = data.get('col2')
            Profile.objects.create(user=user, col1=col1, col2=col2)
```

So, (1) my problem is when creating a user using alternate form, no record is inserted in `allauth` tables, *which i find weird*.

(2) Consider, I signed up using alternate form using E1 as email id. Now I signup via `allauth(FB)` with the same id, it throws an error.

(3) How do I send confirmation mail to the users who signed up in alternate form using `all_auth`.

Comment: Why downvote???

Comment: I'm not a downvoter. Can you explain how you  are saving the `extra_data` ?

Comment: @RajaSimon - A demo snippet `create_profile` is provided in the question. Kindly have a look. Thanks. :)

Comment: just as a good practice notice, don't allow null values on strings, instead use (blank=True, default='', max_length=50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with the library a bit and finally found the solution to my question. I'm pasting it over here for other's to review.

Add a signal `pre_social_login` that'll check for conditions.

```
class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin=None, **kwargs):
        if sociallogin:
            user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
            # If user already exists in custom local form, then login directly.
            # Save/Update his details in social login tables.
            if user:
                # create or update social login tables to maintain the uniformity in the code.
                token = sociallogin.token.token
                socialaccount = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=user).first()
                if socialaccount:  # If it exists, then update social tables.
                    # updating account.
                    socialaccount.extra_data = extra_data
                    socialaccount.save()
                    # updating token.
                    SocialToken.objects.filter(account=socialaccount) \
                                       .update(token=token)
                else:  # else create.
                    # saving Social EmailAddress.
                    EmailAddress.objects.create(email=email, user=user)

                    # saving social account.
                    provider = 'facebook'
                    kwargs = {
                        'uid': extra_data.get('id'),
                        'provider': provider,
                        'extra_data': extra_data,
                        'user': user
                    }
                    socialaccount = SocialAccount.objects.create(**kwargs)

                    # saving social token.
                    app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider=provider)
                    kwargs = {
                        'token': token,
                        'account': socialaccount,
                        'app': app
                    }
                    SocialToken.objects.create(**kwargs)

                # finally login.
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                login(request, user)
                raise ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect(reverse('index')))
```